# Selecting text by whole words using mouse click

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way, using AHK or otherwise, to select "only words" and not individual letters, like in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

It should be such that even if the mouse pointer begins to select text at the middle of a word, it must autofill the unselected text on the left. Similarly if the pointer ends with an incomplete selection of the word, it must fill the leftover on the right.

Thank you.

Comment: In many programs a double click selects the current word under the mouse pointer. A triple click the entire paragraph. If you want to use the caret position I would send a ctrl+left to jump to the start of the word, then a ctrl+shift+right to select to next word.

Answer (score 0):

Press F1 to select the word under the mouse pointer, even if the window under the pointer isn't active:

```
#If (A_Cursor = "IBeam") ; the mouse pointer is over selectable text 

    $F1:: click 2  ; double click

#If
```